# Issue with "ServerName" upon Boot or Restart of Apache2

Tags: 10.04, apache2

## The Question:

I keep getting this error on all apache2 restarts I have on my box here at my home, and I cannot figure out how to get rid of it:
`* Restarting web server apache2

apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName`

Any suggestions as to how I can get rid of this?

## Included files / updates

**/etc/hosts**: http://pastebin.com/nkXgE97U

Comment: it's possible your hosts file is messed up. what are the contents of `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: @RolandTaylor: updated.

Comment: Now I won't call myself an expert, but I don't see an entry for 127.0.0.1, which is normally there by default. Maybe you need to add an entry for it (but I will wait till someone can confirm this). To my knowledge your system will be expecting such an entry to supply the host name for the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit this file:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And put this line in there:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Apache is throwing the error as it doesn't, by default, have a ServerName configured.